# Maximizing a skew-symmetric 4D cross product

Tags: derivatives, optimization

How do I find two orthonormal 4D vectors, $(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3)$, which maximize functions like this:

$-19x_1y_0 - 33x_2y_0 + 11x_3y_0 + 19x_0y_1 - 21x_2y_1 - 33x_3y_1 + 33x_0y_2 + 21x_1y_2 - 30x_3y_2 - 11x_0y_3 + 33x_1y_3 + 30x_2y_3$

Notice that the coefficients are skew-symmetric in case that helps.  I tried direct substitution and Lagrange multipliers and things just got ugly.

Comment: Use a numerical constrained nonlinear optimizer. The orthonormality conditions would be the constraints. Use a global optimizer if you want to ensure finding the global (i.e., true) maximum.